# Spring boot controller test - mock repository but test actual service

Tags: spring, spring-boot, integration-testing

I'm trying to write a test class in **Spring boot 2** where:

- I want to test a controller
- I want to mock a repository
- I want to inject a service as is (i.e. *without* mocking it)

The class looks something like:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@WebMvcTest(MyController.class)
public class MyControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    @MockBean
    private MyRepositoryInterface myRepository;
    @Autowired
    private MyService myService;
    // tests follow ...
}
```

The (only) implementation of `MyService` is annotated with `@Service` and allows repository injection through its `@Autowired` constructor:

```
@Service
public class MyActualService implements MyService {
    private MyRepository repo;
    @Autowired
    public MyActualService(MyRepository repo) {
        this.repo = repo;
    }
    // ...
}
```

I'm getting a `NoSuchBeanDefinitionException` when running the test, broadly stating "no `MyService` available".

I suspect I may require a specific configuration for the test to pick up the service, but I'm getting utterly confused by the online literature available.

Any pointer?

Comment: Per [the docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) the autoconfiguration is explicitly *"not `@Component`, `@Service` or `@Repository` beans"*.

Comment: @jonrsharpe aHA. Thanks, looking into.

Comment: @jonrsharpe just solved my case after actually reading the docs (ahem). Do you think answering this (with some sub code) may have any value, or should I just delete in your opinion?

Comment: I think you could write the answer.

Comment: @jonrsharpe cheers, will do soon.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

After consulting the [docs](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/api/org/springframework/boot/test/autoconfigure/web/servlet/WebMvcTest.html) (I did not read properly in the first instance), as pointed out by [jonsharpe](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3001761/jonrsharpe), I managed to wrangle a working solution:

```
@RunWith(SpringRunner.class)
@SpringBootTest
@AutoConfigureMockMvc
public class MyControllerTest {
    @Autowired
    private MockMvc mvc;
    @MockBean
    private MyRepositoryInterface myRepository;

    // no need to reference the service explicitly

    // ... tests follow
}
```

The above retrieves the service as it loads the full application configuration, and only mocks the repository as directed.

I could probably write an ad-hoc configuration to better fit the requirements, but this works "out of the box" already.

Comment: another one possible solution is use @Import with your service. But your're right, better just use springboottest)

Comment: How to include spring security using this way of configuration?

Comment: I lost track here, and it looks like this Q&A got upvotes recently (and no other answer has been posted), so I'm going to self-accept this as the least worst solution - can always accept a better answer later.